# middleware updates request.user, but request.user becomes AnonymousUser in view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-middleware

I wrote a simple JWT middleware to get user from the JWT. The method `get_user_from_jwt` returns a User object.

```
# app.middlewares.py

class JwtMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        self.process_request(request)
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.user = self.get_user_from_jwt(request.headers)

    def get_user_pk_from_jwt(self, auth_header: str) -> int:
        _, token = auth_header.split(' ')
        decoded_payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
        user_pk = decoded_payload.get('user_id', None)
        return user_pk

    def get_user_from_jwt(self, auth_header: str) -> User:
        auth_header = headers.get('Authorization', None)
        if auth_header:
            try:
                user_pk = self.get_user_pk_from_jwt(auth_header)
                user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_pk)
                return user
            except Exception as error:
                logging.error(f'Error decoding JWT due to: {str(error)}')
                raise AuthenticationFailed
        else:
            raise NotAuthenticated
```

In settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'app.middlewares.JwtMiddleware',
]
```

When I log, `request.user` is set to the proper User instance at the middleware level, but once at a view, `request.user` becomes AnonymousUser. I tried switching the orders of the middlewares too. Any ideas how I can update what request.user means inside my views using a middleware?

Comment: And are you sure the that the request.user that was set isn't AnonymousUser in the case of failed authentication? Can you show the implementation of `self.get_user_from_jwt()`?

Comment: @Ken4scholars, yes I am sure otherwise an exception would be raised, I've included the method for more context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using JWT token authentication with Django rest framework, then you need to update your authentication backends. The request.user is set automatically, when a user is authenticated. So if you are not authenticating the user, your request.user will be over-written by AnonymousUser.

You need to write an authentication Class, for example, JWTAuth, which should inherit the BaseAuthetication.

```
from rest_framework import authentication, exceptions

class JWTAuth(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    authentication_header_prefix = 'Bearer'

    def authenticate(self, request):
        request.user = None
        auth_header = authentication.get_authorization_header(request).split()
        auth_header_prefix = self.authentication_header_prefix.lower()

        if not auth_header:
            return None

        prefix = auth_header[0].decode('utf-8')
        token = auth_header[1].decode('utf-8')

        if prefix.lower() != auth_header_prefix:
            return None

        return self._authenticate_credentials(request, token)

    def _authenticate_credentials(self, request, token):
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
        except:
            msg = 'Invalid authentication. Could not decode token.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=payload['id'])

        except User.DoesNotExist:
            msg = 'No user matching this token was found.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        if not user.is_active:
            msg = 'This user has been deactivated.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        return user, token
```

in your settings file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
                         'JWTAuth',
    )
```

If you are also trying to customize your Login process, then you will have to update AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in your settings file.