# "Token contained no recognizable user identification" while creating custom django jwt token

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have created my login view which on successful login returns access token and refresh token..Then on accessing any view the user have to attach this access token as bearer token in every url..
I have manually created my access token and refresh token . But i have inherited restframework_simplejwt.views.TokenRefreshView which will return an access token for each refresh token..
All this is working fine...
Now i have used permission_classes((IsAuthenticated)) above my home_api_view and when i paste the access token over the homepage url it says  "Token contained no recognizable user identification"

my views.py

```py
    @api_view(['POST','GET',])
    @permission_classes([])
    def login_view(request):
        username = request.data.get("username")
        password = request.data.get("password")
        response = Response()

        user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first() #This will return directly the username . If you dont use .first() it will return a dictionary
            access_token = Generate_Access_Token(user)
            refresh_token = Generate_Refresh_Token(user)
            response.data={'refresh_token':refresh_token,'access_token':access_token}
            return response
        else:
            return HttpResponse("USERNAME or PASSWORD ERROR!!!")
```

utils.py

```py
def Generate_Access_Token(user):
    access_token_payload = {
        'token_type':'access',
        'exp':datetime.datetime.utcnow()+datetime.timedelta(days=0,minutes=5),
        'jti': uuid4().hex,
        'user':user.username,
        'id':user.id,
        'iat':datetime.datetime.utcnow(),

    }

    access_token = jwt.encode(access_token_payload,settings.SECRET_KEY,algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
    return access_token


def Generate_Refresh_Token(user):
    refresh_token_payload = {
        'token_type':'refresh',
        'id': user.id,
        'exp' :datetime.datetime.utcnow()+datetime.timedelta(days=7),
        'iat':datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        'jti': uuid4().hex
    }

    refresh_token = jwt.encode(refresh_token_payload,settings.SECRET_KEY,algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
    return refresh_token
```

Comment: Your login and token creation functionality look fine. You also need to write a method to authenticate with token rather than username and password. Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62112041/12840065

Comment: When we use built in token obtain pair view and get an access token then there we don't need to authenticate those tokens...then why do we have to authenticate the token generated by the custom function...??

Comment: Because if you use inbuilt token authentication, in that case, Django automatically calls up authenticate credentials. But we use custom tokens, Django does not know how to decode it. That's why you are getting the error because Django can't find the ID or username. So you need  to override authenticate_credentials and should return user and token as discussed in the above given post

Comment: ImportError: Could not import 'JWTAuth' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: JWTAuth doesn't look like a module path.

Comment: when i paste your code in settings.py i get the error mentioned above and when i copy it in views.py and then import in settings py i get following error   ::::::     django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Comment: Dear, You need to provide the full path to JWTAuth. See the other settings to get an idea. You need not import it in settings. To get an idea about how to provide the full path, have a look at middlewares already defined in settings. Also check your SECRET_KEY in settings in not empty.

Comment: If you are still not able to solve, have a look at any tutorial on Django

Comment: Can we have a personal chat ??? Please drop a way to communicate with you...

Comment: Yes, We can do that here. Let do at 3:00 PM IST?

Comment: 9805440315 my whatsapp number ..Lets have a conversation here..Message me whenever you are free..