# User authentication with Django and NextJS

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, next.js

I am building a project that uses Django Rest Framework as the backend and NextJS serves React frontend. How can I integrate user authentication using these two technologies?

In the future we might build a mobile app as well, so we need the backend to be consistent.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the JWT tokens for authentication. You will not face any problem if you change your frontend. To get an idea on implementation, check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62112041/12840065